Aliasing Columns in Complex Teradata SQL Query with Multiple CTEs
I have been trying to connect my Databricks notebook to Teradata to pass my SQL as a string and retrieve a DataFrame of the data. One requirement is that all derived columns must be explicitly named in Teradata. My SQL query involves multiple Common Table Expressions (CTEs), and I am finding it challenging to determine how to alias my columns properly.
There are columns with common names in certain tables, and when I alias them to the same name, I am concerned that the results might differ between the original and aliased queries.
Here's a simplified outline of my query structure (using dummy representations for the columns):
SQL Query Structure
1. CTE1

Columns:

column1
column2
common_column
column4
...



2. CTE2

Columns:

columnA
common_column
columnC
columnD
...



3. CTE3

Columns:

columnX
common_column
columnY
columnZ
...



Final Select Statement

Columns:

All columns from CTE3
Constant value 'LH'
current_timestamp(0)



Example SQL Query
WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT 
        column1,
        column2,
        common_column,
        column4
    FROM table1
    WHERE condition1
),
CTE2 AS (
    SELECT 
        columnA,
        common_column,
        columnC,
        columnD
    FROM table2
    JOIN CTE1 ON CTE1.common_column = table2.common_column
    WHERE condition2
),
CTE3 AS (
    SELECT 
        columnX,
        common_column,
        columnY,
        columnZ
    FROM table3
    JOIN CTE2 ON CTE2.common_column = table3.common_column
    WHERE condition3
)
SELECT 
    CTE3.*,
    'Constantvalue' AS constant_value,
    current_timestamp(0) AS query_timestamp
FROM CTE3

Concerns:

How to properly alias columns that have the same name across different tables and CTEs.
Ensuring that the results from the aliased query remain consistent with the original query.

Any tips or best practices on how to manage column aliasing in such complex queries would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Try CTE2 AS (  SELECT ...    CTE1.common_column,...) and CTE3 AS (  SELECT ...    CTE2.common_column,...)

Why do you think you need to alias columns with the same name that are in different tables or CTEs?  Just qualify every reference to a column (always, not just when you have identically named columns).  BTW, your query as written will fail with column common_column is ambiguous.

Both prior commenters are correct. The solution is to qualify the column in your select. Two cents - this is good practice just in general whenever you have more than 1 table in the mix even if the column names aren't shared. Future you and readers of your code will be happy to see select a.SomeFieldInA, b.SomeFieldInB from table_a a inner join table_b ....  and not have to guess or inspect to figure out which field is coming from where.
